# NTFS mounting problem

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs, opensuse, ntfs-3g

#### Partitions

```
Device    Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    53944319    26971136    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        53946272    60034904     3044316+  83  Linux
/dev/sda3   *    60035072   201345023    70654976    5  Extended
/dev/sda4       201345024   625141759   211898368    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       187015168   201345023     7164928   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6        60037120   101980159    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       101982208   187013119    42515456   83  Linux
```

sda3 is an extended 60 GB partition. When I installed OpenSuSE it automatically created two partitions from sda3 (sda6 for root and sda7 for home).

Now I can't mount NTFS partitions. How can I mount them?

I tried `mount` command and now checked ntfs-3g but it warns me that:

> Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.

Comment: You can usually mount them by installing the right tools. The tools are usually called `mount.fstype`. And you probably want `ntfs3g`.

Comment: `now I can't mount NTFS...` _now_ ? Do you mean that it used to work, and no longer does? Or is this just the conjunctive verb you've chosen to introduce your problem? What command are you trying to use to mount your filesystems? (Or, what `/etc/fstab` entries are you trying to use?)

Answer (score 1):

You can issue the `mount` command to get a list of all mounted filesystems, where they are mounted, what device they are on and there options:

```
user@host:~$ mount
/dev/sde1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
...snip...
/dev/sdd1 on /media/Windows type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sde2 on /home type ext4 (rw,commit=0)
```

In the above output, for example, you can see that I have an NTFS partition on device `/dev/sdd1` mounted at `/media/Windows`

An NTFS volume will appear as either using `ntfs-3g` or `fuseblk` on most systems.